# Cursor image not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div with the following css.

```
.mydiv
{
    cursor: url("/image/cursor-hand.png"), move;
}
```

Works fine in chrome, Firefox and safari, But doesn't work in IE.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE doesn't support normal graphics, you need a [cursor file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.cur) `.cur`.

See also:

- quirksmode.org: [compatibility list: Cursor](http://quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html#t013)
- [MDN: Using URL values for the cursor property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property)