# Evolution of my custom cursor code: How do I get it to work in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, custom-cursor

I have a custom cursor that is using an image. My original code:

```
cursor:url(../images/drag_mini_bg.png);
```

I then discovered that Firefox requires you to define a default backup in case the image is not found, and changed it to:

```
cursor:url(../images/drag_mini_bg.png), default;
```

This worked for Firefox and Chrome, but not IE. I read that IE uses a [different source](http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2008/01/08/cross-browser-custom-css-cursors/) for the path than other browsers and implemented [this solution](http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2008/01/08/cross-browser-custom-css-cursors/):

```
cursor:url(../images/drag_mini_bg.png),url(/images/drag_mini_bg.png),default;
```

(The second url is relative to the html file rather than the css file that this code is included in.)

This didn't seem to help, so I found out about [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222328/cursor-image-not-working-in-ie) and changed the image to a .cur file:

```
cursor:url(../images/drag_mini_bg.cur),url(/images/drag_mini_bg.cur),default;
```

However, it is still not showing up in IE. Anything else I can try?

Comment: have you tried Microsoft Windows Animated Cursor (.ani)

Comment: [Jason Gennaro](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7419342/1135581) answer may help you.

Comment: @Rahul - I put in code to handle that bug that he mentions (the second url) and it didn't help...

Answer (score 1):

Most of what you've read is correct, but I'll make a few amendments:

- Firefox does indeed require the additional parameter to be added. My understanding is that the ideal value for this is `auto`. But if `default` works for you, use it.
- As you've been told, IE can only display cursors of the `.cur` file type. PNGs and GIFs do not work.
- However, I've never heard anything about IE using a different path; the same path has always worked fine for me in all browsers (when using a CUR file, of course). You might want to provide a reference to where you heard this, but I'd suggest that dropping the second URL may solve your problems.

There's a good site called Quirksmode that has a lot of browser compatibility tables. In particular, they have a very [thorough table covering CSS cursors](http://quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html), which shows exactly how to format it to make it work in all browsers, with examples and notes about the quirks.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I included my reference for the IE path bug in the question... And removing the second url doesn't help. And thanks for the quirksmode link, but nothing there actually helps me :-/

Comment: another SO topic to follow :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419314/custom-cursor-image-doesnt-work-in-all-ies

Answer (score 0):

If you're still trying to figure this out 8 years later...I'll add that some browsers have a maximum image size, so maybe yours was too big. I believe you want to keep it under 32x32 pixels.