# Onmouseover cursor doesn't change in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, cursor, onmouseover

This is my JS code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function leftCur(elem) {
          elem.style.cursor = 'url("izgled/slike/right.png"), auto';
       };
    </script>
```

And this is part of my HTML code:

```
<div class="mainleft" onmouseover="leftCur(this)">
```

When I hover with mouse over a div, mouse pointer changes picture, it works in Chrome and FF but it doesn't in IE.

THx.

Comment: Your code doesn't make a lot of sense. First, you posted "rightCur" but the event handler calls "leftCur".  The handler assigns the return value of the function to the "value" property of the element, but `<div>` elements don't have a "value", and if "leftCur" is anything like "rightCur" it doesn't return anything anyway.

Comment: Why are you not doing this in pure CSS? `div.mainleft:hover { cursor : move; }`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cursor image not working in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222328/cursor-image-not-working-in-ie)

Comment: Sorry i corrected the code. I tried also with .gif image but it doesnt work

Comment: I tried with css, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least some versions of Internet Explorer do not support `.png` or `.gif` cursors.

MDN has a great reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/cursor/url?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FUsing_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property)

Try using a `.cur` cursor instead.